# extracting multiple values from JSON

Tags: json, node.js

In Node.js 6.10, an API call returns JSON string:

in C# code is `return "{\"response\" : \" " + responseMsg + " \" , \"isNewActiveDirectoryUser\" : \" " + isNewActiveDUser + " \"}";`

this returns

```
"\"{\\\"response\\\" : \\\" Not latest version of file, update not performed \\\" , \\\"isNewActiveDirectoryUser\\\" : \\\" False \\\"}\""
```

I want to extract response & isNewActiveDirectoryUser and place the result in variables.

I have tried

```
context.done(null, body);
    var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
    let valueReturned1 = jsonBody.response; //have tried this
            let valueReturned2 =jsonBody["response"]; //and this
```

both display undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

I can console.log the body and it is populated

Comment: Your json is double stringified.  `JSON.parse(JSON.parse("\"{\\\"response\\\" : \\\" Not latest version of file, update not performed \\\" , \\\"isNewActiveDirectoryUser\\\" : \\\" False \\\"}\"")).response === " Not latest version of file, update not performed "`  Sounds like you need to fix it on the C# side

Comment: thank you kindly sir, if you make that the answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is double stringified.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.parse("\"{\\\"response\\\" : \\\" Not latest version of file, update not performed \\\" , \\\"isNewActiveDirectoryUser\\\" : \\\" False \\\"}\"")).response === " Not latest version of file, update not performed "
```

Sounds like you need to fix it on the C# side